# Why is DateParse using European standard date format here

Tags: ruby

Passing in the following is getting interpreted as February, 12th 2013 instead of December 2nd, 2013.. is there a reason for that? Do I have to change some system default somewhere? This is using Ruby 2.0.0

```
2.0.0-p247-turbo :003 > dt=DateTime.parse("12/2/2013 1:00:00 PM")
 => #<DateTime: 2013-02-12T13:00:00+00:00 ((2456336j,46800s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.0.0-p247-turbo :004 > dt.day
 => 12 
2.0.0-p247-turbo :005 > dt.month
 => 2 
2.0.0-p247-turbo :006 > dt.year
 => 2013
```

Comment: Pass a format argument to the method. You can look it up, get it from the client, the server, even hard code it, don't rely on system culture for parsing dates though. That's a bug fest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime)?

```
DateTime.strptime("12/2/2013 1:00:00 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
```

I don't know if this behaviour is dependent on system settings, or if it's what Ruby always does. Anyway, I'd rather have this requirement (that dates should be parsed in this way) obvious in the code.

See also: http://foragoodstrftime.com (where I got the format string from)